# All Dropdowns at once within Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I having trouble with making separate dropdowns open from a pullover. If you were to look at my JSFiddle here: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/arockwell/j06tovw0/)

You would see that whenever an item within the pullover is clicked, that all existing dropdowns show up.

Is there any way to distinguish the following to make sure the desired dropdown shows up?:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Level 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have two dropdowns `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` wrapped inside just one `<div class="dropdown">`. This will indeed cause both dropdowns to display because bootstrap uses those class names to determine what to display.

So if you wrap the second dropdown in it's own `<div>` you should get the desired behavior. I'd also move the `id="parent"` up a level to it's own `<div>` so a structure like:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
      <!-- Level 1 Cascade -->
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <!-- Items within Level 1 Cascade -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- Level 2 Cascade -->
        <li>
          <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
            <!-- Level 3 Cascade -->
            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            <!-- Level 3 Cascade -->
            <li>
              <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <!-- so on and so forth -->
                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 4</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Level 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 5</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Level 3 Cascade -->
            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Level 2 Cascade -->
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <!-- Level 2 Cascade -->
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
            <!-- Level 3 Cascade -->
            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            <!-- Level 3 Cascade -->
            <li>
              <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <!-- so on and so forth -->
                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 4</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Level 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 5</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Level 3 Cascade -->
            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 1-2<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <!-- Items within Level 1 Cascade -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- Level 2 Cascade -->
        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've modified the fiddle accordingly:
http://jsfiddle.net/mjcwly/srporvqh/